# Lambda not consuming all messages in queue after failing to process

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS queue, name events, with a lambda trigger, named consumer. Furthermore, I have a Dead letter Queue, name poison_events, configured on the queue, events (*Not the Lambda*). When the lambda throw an error it will not delete the received messages, as expected, and leave the messages in the queue. The lambda will attempt to process the messages again and this is evident by the receive count of the messages increasing.

My Goal is to have all message that are not able to be processed sent to the Dead letter Queue after exceeding the MaxReceiveCount of 10.
My problem begin when the messages available in the queue increases and the lambda does not scale to process the available messages.

I am under the assumption that the lambda will scale such that it will process all messages in the queue to the point that the receive count will exceed the maxReceiveCount and be sent to the Dead Letter Queue. Yet this is not the case, the lambda will only scale to around 100 invocations per minute which is not enough to process the messages.

Note that the concurrency of the lambda is set to the default, 1000

I have two working theories:

1. lambda will first process new messages and only scale to to handle new messages, before processing messages that are available in the queue.
2. My second theory is that the lambda error count is so high that aws will refuse to scale out functions to process the available messages.

**lambda invocations**
[image: lambda invocations]

**Available messages**
[image: Available messages]

**Error count and success rate**
[image: Error count and success rate]

**lambda concurrency**
[image: lambda concurrency]

Comment: Note that SQS can deliver messages in batches to a single Lambda invocation. The default batch size is 10.

Comment: @jarmod Should the amount of invocations grow as the the number of available messages increase. The current amount of invocations (~100) and the batch size is not enough to process the current amount of available messages (~400K)